# Reading a 2 dimensional array or sharePoint list from InfoPath

Tags: c#, sharepoint, infopath

I am new at C# and InfoPath. Using SharePoint 2007 and InfoPath 2007. I have an InfoPath form that I want to read values from a list but I want to read a value based on column name *and* row # so in C# code this would be a 2 dimensional array or List<>.  Is it possible to read from a SharePoint list without writing c# code (workflow) to access the values in the list?

7/25/11: I couldn't comment or reply so am editing my original post instead:

@Andreas Thank you for your idea.

Your suggestion is not exactly what I want to do although I am doing the tutorials from msdn that you recommended.  Most of it is review for me but I am also learning some new tricks (i.e. certificate signing).  Anyway, I have a list in SharePoint that is a per diem rate chart for travelers.  I am trying to figure out a way to pick the correct rate, based on days of travel and destination zip code.  The SharePoint list column name are rate values like $46, $51, $76 and the rows are breakfast, lunch, dinner incidentals, "first or last day of travel".

If rate = $46 and days of travel are > zero and < 3, (i.e. 2 days total) then "first and last day of travel" per diem applies.

My dilema is how do I read the value (rate) for "first and last day of travel" if column is $46.  This would be a 2 dimensional array or list, right? Can I read the value with IP rules or do I need to write custom code to read from the list?

Answer (score 0):

From what I've understood, you want to create a connection to a SharePoint list/library and display it's contents in an InfoPath Form in a 2 dimensional way => Table, am i right?

If so, this two links might help you out.

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/infopath-help/add-a-data-connection-to-a-sharepoint-document-library-or-list-HP010093160.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb267335(v=office.12).aspx